DataFrame.dtypes doesn't work after astype() in pandas
I've transformed OrderDate column from its existing object data type into a 'datetime64[ns]' with astype method.
But after dtypes() I saw it didn't work.
Why?
Thanks.
`df_raw.OrderDate.astype('datetime64[ns]'),
`astype done
df_raw.dtypes
dtypes not changed

Please share your code snippet, it's hard to tell from just this.

I think (assuming) you didn't assign is back to the column is causing the issue
Code working on sample data as below
          Duration  Pulse    Maxpulse  Calories
     0       60      110       130       409.1
     1       60      117       145       479.0
     2       60      103       135       340.0
     3       45      109       175       282.4
     4       45      117       148       406.0

Code sample
print(df.dtypes)

print("----------------")
df.Duration = df.Duration.astype('int32')
print(df.dtypes)

Got below response
 Duration      int64
 Pulse         int64
 Maxpulse      int64
 Calories    float64
 dtype: object
 ----------------
 Duration      int32
 Pulse         int64
 Maxpulse      int64
 Calories    float64
 dtype: object

Now for the answer to this question, if you did only
df_raw.OrderDate.astype('datetime64[ns]')
Try doing
df_raw.OrderDate = df_raw.OrderDate.astype('datetime64[ns]')

Update: for multiple columns as @user19077881 mentioned in comment, you can use dictionary as below
df = df.astype({'col1': 'object', 'col2': 'int'})


Thank you. It worked. But if I need to change type of several columns do i need to make it one by one or there is simpliest way?

To change multiple columns use a dictionary as in the first answer to this SO question link

This worked. Thank you. I was trying to make this https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html, as i need to transform multiple columns to one data type, but it is a little bit difficult for a new one... >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
...                    'month': [2, 3],
...                    'day': [4, 5]})



pd.to_datetime(df)
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns] do i need to put every columns like this?




Didn't get you? Are you asking for exact implementation of your case for multiple columns?

yes, about my case.

df = df.astype({'year': 'datetime64[ns]', 'month': 'datetime64[ns]', 'day': 'datetime64[ns]' })
if the above helps your case you can accept the answer if not trying out things will give a better idea or understanding of operations.

ok, fine. Previous was better.

Previous answer?

df = df.astype({'col1': 'object', 'col2': 'int'}) this one worked.
